# Iterate through VBA dropdown list

Tags: excel, vba, list, drop-down-menu

[image]

I have three dropdown validation lists and I am trying to write some code that iterates through all of the "Management Methods" permutations that are available.

I can figure out the first step of iterating through one list (for example [Iterate through an Excel dropdown/validation list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30603004/iterate-through-an-excel-dropdown-validation-list) and others) but I can't work out how to go through three of them.

Ideally, I would like this to be written in a way that works even if you add more options.

To achieve this I figure you want a way of counting how many options there are in each list and then iterating through from 0-n.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Sub LoopThroughList()
Dim Dropdown1, Dropdown2, Dropdown3 As String
Dim Range1, Range2, Range3 As Range
Dim option1, option2, option3 As Range

' *** SET DROPDOWN LOCATIONS HERE ***
' ***********************************

    Dropdown1 = "C6"
    Dropdown2 = "D6"
    Dropdown3 = "E6"

' ***********************************
' ***********************************

Set Range1 = Evaluate(Range(Dropdown1).Validation.Formula1)
Set Range2 = Evaluate(Range(Dropdown2).Validation.Formula1)
Set Range3 = Evaluate(Range(Dropdown3).Validation.Formula1)

For Each option1 In Range1
    For Each option2 In Range2
        For Each option3 In Range3

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C6:E6").Copy
            With Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With


        Next option3
    Next option2
Next option1


End Sub
```

At the moment I get this:

[image]

This is iterating through the crop type dropdown but returning the same for pest and management methods. The code I used to create the dropdown list is as below:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C6")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("D6:E6").ClearContents
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to perform loops that will iterate through every possible combination is to use a `For Each` loop. You can find more info about them [here](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/loop-through-defined-range.html) and [here](http://www.homeandlearn.org/for_each.html) and [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/vba/vba_foreach_loop.htm) and [here](http://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/vba-loops-for-while-until-loops/)....... !!!  Etcetera....

This will loop through every combination of 3 dropdown lists. You will need to change the location of the dropdowns in my code.

```
Sub LoopThroughList()
Dim Dropdown1, Dropdown2, Dropdown3 As String
Dim Range1, Range2, Range3 As Range
Dim option1, option2, option3 As Range

' *** SET DROPDOWN LOCATIONS HERE ***
' ***********************************

    Dropdown1 = "D8"
    Dropdown2 = "E8"
    Dropdown3 = "F8"

' ***********************************
' ***********************************

Set Range1 = Evaluate(Range(Dropdown1).Validation.Formula1)
Set Range2 = Evaluate(Range(Dropdown2).Validation.Formula1)
Set Range3 = Evaluate(Range(Dropdown3).Validation.Formula1)

For Each option1 In Range1
    For Each option2 In Range2
        For Each option3 In Range3

            ' *** PERFORM CODE HERE ***
            ' EXAMPLE
            ' Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1) = option1
            ' Sheets(1).Cells(2, 1) = option2
            ' etc...

        Next option3
    Next option2
Next option1


End Sub
```

EDIT:

```
Sub LoopThroughList()
Dim Dropdown1, Dropdown2, Dropdown3 As String
Dim Range1, Range2, Range3 As Range
Dim option1, option2, option3 As Range

Dim Counter As Long

Counter = 1

' *** SET DROPDOWN LOCATIONS HERE ***
' ***********************************

    Dropdown1 = "C6"
    Dropdown2 = "D6"
    Dropdown3 = "E6"

' ***********************************
' ***********************************

Set Range1 = Evaluate(Range(Dropdown1).Validation.Formula1)
Set Range2 = Evaluate(Range(Dropdown2).Validation.Formula1)
Set Range3 = Evaluate(Range(Dropdown3).Validation.Formula1)

For Each option1 In Range1
    For Each option2 In Range2
        For Each option3 In Range3

            Sheets(2).Cells(Counter, 1) = option1
            Sheets(2).Cells(Counter, 2) = option2
            Sheets(2).Cells(Counter, 3) = option3
            Counter = Counter + 1

        Next option3
    Next option2
Next option1


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I have tried to use this in my code (see the edit in my post) but it doesn't seem to be getting past the first option.

Comment: If you are trying to Get a list of all the possible combinations, try my second code above

Comment: Sorry I have been spending some more time on this and it actually only iterates through the first dropdown list but returns the same for the second and third: in my answer I have included and example of what it produces.